# not line graphs

Tags: graph-theory

[image]

How do I show these are not line graphs? When I tried taking every vertex as an edge and every edge as a common vertex between the edges, I could draw the original graphs. But I need to show that these are not line graphs.

Please help me with this. Thank you

Comment: "When I tried taking every vertex as an edge and every edge as a common vertex between the edges, I could draw the original graphs." If you *could* actually do this, then they would be line graphs. These are not line graphs because you can't. Maybe the "original" graphs you draw also have some extra adjacencies?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand, but is this not as simple as the fact that these two graphs are in  Beineke's set of forbidden subgraphs for a graph G such that L(H) = G ?

Comment: @gilleain I assume the problem is meant to teach the intuition behind (part of) that set of forbidden subgraphs. Of course, teaching intuition does not work if your approach to problem-solving is "post a problem on MSE and hope someone does it for you".

Comment: @Misha Lavrov oh i see - I didnt mean to give away the answer, I just assumed it was more complex than that given it only took a few minutes to find the solution. I guess actually showing why the claw is forbidden is more tricky

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on Misha's answer: here is what I advise you to do.

Keep your drawings of the (supposed) original graphs somewhere, and go walk outside for enough time to have completely forgotten about the graphs in the drawings above. Return to your drawings of the original graphs and start drawing *their* line graphs with fresh eyes as if this were a stand-alone assignment. (Imagine you were given these graphs by someone else instead of having constructed them by the above method.)

Then, after having drawn these line graphs, check how they differ from the graphs you started with. This should tell you something about why these can't be line graphs. (Roughly speaking: if they *were* line graphs they should have been able to the new, actual, line graphs you just drew, but having these drawings concretely in front of you you can make this a bit more precise and mathematical.)